# Trouble getting log4j to output to file

Tags: java, maven, jar, log4j

I build a jar using a Maven profile and want to the log4j output to redirect to a file.

Here's my log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=./reporting.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and here's the command i run from bash:

```
java -jar -Dlog4j.configuration=~/log4j.properties myjar.jar
```

all of the logging output is going to stdout despite all of this. any suggestions?

EDIT:

Tried:

- Including properties file in root directory of jar, where it should be picked up by default
- Specifying class path at runtime: -cp
- Adding class path in manifest through maven
- Specifying properties file at runtime: -Dlog4j.properties=
- Specifying individual properties at runtime: Dlog4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,F -Dlog4j.appender.F=…

None of this has worked - I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: have you tried using another path instead of ./reporting.log? Maybe to know if it could be the problem?

Comment: another reason may be that `~/log4j.properties` isn't expanded to actual path, try to use absolute path instead.

Comment: Have you tried this with an absolute path?

Comment: i changed the path to the properties file to an absolute path as well as the output path for the log - no luck

Comment: You don't have another log4j.properties file in the jar, do you?

Comment: @BalintBako I do - this same properties file is included in the root directory of the jar. it doesn't seem to be running from there either.

Comment: I was worried that you have a different one there. log4j loads the prop file automatically from the classpath, so you might want to add the folder of the file to classpath with a `-cp "<path>"` switch. (I don't know why is it not loaded form the jar)

Comment: i don't have a classpath specified in my jar's manifest, though. does it still look in the root folder of the jar automatically?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are logging using log4j and not with System.prinln("...")?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, `log4j.properties` is located at `/user/home` run

```
java -cp /user/home:. -jar myjar.jar
```

- By default, the name of the configuration file is already `log4j.properties`.
- The file specified in `-Dlog4j.configuration` *also* needs to be in your *classpath*.

So, if your properties file was `/user/home/temp-log4j.properties` then you would run

```
java -cp /user/home:. -Dlog4j.configuration=temp-log4j.properties -jar myjar.jar
```

Comment: If his `.jar` has a manifest with a classpath this will be completely ignored.

Comment: Properties file is /Users/benkaiser/log4j.properties. Ran the following command:

Comment: java -cp /Users/benkaiser:. -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties -jar myjar.jar

Comment: @benjaminhkaiser Add -Dlog4j.debug as well to see log4j internal debug messages. Would help to troubleshoot. Also, verify there's no other properties file within the jar.

Comment: there is another properties file - this same one is located in the root directory of the jar. i'll remove it, re-jar and try again.

Comment: no internal debug messages printed, error persists. any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you doing anything special like: `PropertyConfigurator.configure()` or `BasicConfigurator.configure()` etc. or just plain `Logger.getLogger()`s? Could you also check for any spelling mistakes in filename? No offence though. :)

Comment: Can you check if its `/users` instead of `/Users` (notice the case)?

Comment: just plain Logger.getLoggers()s everywhere. no spelling or case mistakes either, as far as i can tell.

Comment: I would suggest you bundle a new jar with a single main-class that does nothing but log a statement. Then try to run it as before. What this would help is to identify if it's an environment problem or related to jar's codebase.

Comment: @benjaminhkaiser How's log4j's jar getting added to the classpath? You said there's nothing on the Manifest and you sure aren't adding it on the command-line.

Comment: i'm not generating the jar from the command line, i'm generating it through maven. log4j is added during the maven build. i'm using the shaded pom plugin which automatically pulls all dependencies into the jar.

Comment: Yes, that's fine but running it through `java` directly needs log4j jars to be present on the classpath as well. Try `-cp /users/<username>:.` with log4j.jar in the current directory (which is represented by that `.` on `-cp`).

Answer (score -1):

I use this configuration, maybe something of this configuration could help you, I think that your issue is related to the path, try with a complete path, like the one in FILE.file property, which is an absolute path

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/home/mtataje/logs/repo.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.FILE..MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Hope it could help you, best regards.

Comment: thanks - didn't seem to help. i added this properties file and used an absolute path from the command line but it still printed all output to stdout.